# Crossed arms in FBX-rig where mocap was copied to from BVH

Tags: auto-rig-pro

I didn't find the answer in former posts, and want to copy mocap from BVH-rig (left) to FBX-rig (right). I use Blender 2.9.3.
All FBX-bones are identical to BVH-bones, and I gave them also the same names.
Both have Hips as root.
I used 2 methods for retargeting:

1. the Auto Rig Pro-addon. Result: FBX moves the same as BVH, exept the arms, for they stay crossed.
2. Crtl-L > Link Animation data. Result: FBX keeps rigid, only floats a little around, parallel to movements of BVH.
   [image]
   I'm new in this labyrith stuff. Hope someone can give me the right steps...

Comment: I had the same issue. I'm thinking this maybe because the source and target armature do not share the same rest pose.